# if statement in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, ternary-operator, null

Can someone please help to explain the syntax of the following code for me? It meant to "return ? if `_suit` is `nil`, and return a corresponding string in an array if `_suit` is not `nil`".

```
- (NSString *)suit
{
    return _suit ? _suit : @"?";
}
```

Is it equivalent to the following code?

```
if (!_suit) {
    return @"?";
} else {
    return ?
}
```

Comment: The second return should be `return _suit;`.

Comment: Also, by the way, `return _suit ? _suit : @"?";` can be further simplified to `return _suit ?: @"?";`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a shortening of an if block. It is a conditional operator.

The format is as follows (same in many other languages):

```
condition ? ifTrue: ifFalse;
```

So your code:

```
return _suit ? _suit : @"?";
```

Is the same as

```
if(_suit) {
    return _suit;
} else {
    return @"?";
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html).

Comment: I wouldn't link to Java resources. There are subtle differences between Java and Obj-C.

Comment: Fair enough. If you have a good link to an Obj-C resource, go ahead and edit it in.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not the same. The '?:' operator describes following it is just an if else statement as one-liner:

(if clause) ?  : .

so in your case that would mean:

```
if (!_suit) {
   return @"?";
} else {
   return _suit;
}
```